# Clear form's TextInput when i press connection button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm doing a connection interface in react native using php and sql server .

My problem is :
once i connect and access the application, if i press the return button on my phone, i find the form of login still filled with my name and password .

Is there any solution to clear my form's textInput once I press the connection button?

There is my code of react native :

```
export default class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
       super(props)
       this.state={
         username:'',
         usermail:'',
         password:'',
         secureTextEntry:true,
         iconName:"eye"}}

    userRegister = () =>{
   const {username}=this.state;
   const {usermail}=this.state;
   const {password}=this.state;
  this.setState({password:''});

   fetch('http://192.168.1.4:80/recup.php',{
   method:'post',
   header:{
   'Accept':'application/json',
   'Content-type' :'application/json'
   },
   body:JSON.stringify({email:usermail,password:password})})
   .then((responseData)=>responseData.text())
   .then((responseJson)=>{
    }}).catch((error)=>{console.error(error);})
   }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
            <TextInput placeholder="Enter mail"  style={styles.input}
            onChangeText= {usermail=>this.setState({usermail })}/>

            <View style={styles.pass}>

        <TextInput placeholder="Enter password" style={{flex:1}} secureTextEntry={this.state.secureTextEntry}
        onChangeText= {password=>this.setState({password})}
        />

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.secure} style={{margin:20}}>
            <Icon name="eye" size={20}  /></TouchableOpacity>
            </View>

            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.butt} onPress={this.userRegister}>
                <Text>Connexion</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            </View>
        );

    }

}
```

[and this is my login page to better understand my problem :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9dtV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `userRegister` function to:

```
const userRegister = () =>{
   const username = this.state.username;
   const usermail = this.state.usermail;
   const password = this.state.password;

   this.setState({
      username:'',
      usermail:'',
      password:'',
   });

   fetch('http://192.168.1.4:80/recup.php',{
     method:'post',
     header:{
     'Accept':'application/json',
     'Content-type' :'application/json'
   },
   body:JSON.stringify({email:usermail,password:password})})
     .then((responseData)=>responseData.text())
     .then((responseJson)=>{
        // Success Response
      }})
     .catch((error)=>{console.error(error);})
}
```